# Android multiple JSON web services

Tags: android, web-services, json

I want suggestions about the following case.
I want to create an android application from which I consume web services. Every web service corresponds or return a JSON object of a database table. Obviously I want to link-map the results of every WS to a table on my device(sqlite). Which is the best approach to do such a think. I'm thinking of ormlite. Are there any other ways?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/), which includes a database management tool that will generate all of the Android code (database helpers and ContentProviders) from the tables you define.

Comment: Very interesting option. So, there is no need for an object relational mapper?

Comment: It helps you build all of the boilerplate stuff that goes along with creating a ContentProvider.  You can add some classes to abstract away the ugly side of dealing with Cursors and ContentProviders and make it more ORM-like.  By having a ContentProvider, you can easily tie into other APIs, like CursorLoader though.

Comment: Well your approach is advanced. I installed MOTODEV Studio and it automatically create all the classes to interact with my db!! But i feel lost now... Are there any online resources or sample code to read and try?

Comment: You should start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html.  Also, look at the NotePad example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html